# JXCore - wrong locale parsing (Date.toLocaleString(['de']))

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, jxcore

I'm using JXCore to package the source files of my Node.js App. I have a problem with the locales in the packaged .exe and .jx

```
new Date().toLocaleString(["de"])
```

outputs in `node app.js` `2015-10-29 14:47:18`

in `jx app.jx` and compiled `app.exe` `Thu Oct 29 2015 14:47:18 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)`

Obviously, this isn't the same output. Are there any fixes? Thanks.

Comment: You're passing the locale string in an array; it should just be a string. *edit* oh wait an array should work; never mind.

Comment: It doesn't work passing a string either - just tried it out to check if it matters

Comment: You got this result on same machine ? + Which engine ? (SM, V8, Chakra?)

Comment: The above value appears in V8 engine. In SM engine, it's the following output: `Monday, November 09, 2015 19:10:44`. I have not tested it with the Chakra engine yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I saw this Node.js between their versions reveals this difference too.

```
# node v0.10.38 (v8: '3.14.5.9')
Fri Nov 13 2015 16:20:07 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

# node v0.12.2 (v8: '3.28.73')
11/13/2015, 4:20:07 PM
```

Not going into details this is probably related with underlying V8 engine differences.

JXcore by default uses V8 v3.14.5.9 and produces same output as node v0.10.38.
Probably your `node` is v12+, hence the difference.

But this is true, that JXcore SM (SpiderMonkey) uses format even different from the two above:

```
# jxcore sm
Friday, November 13, 2015 16:20:06
```

Comment: Thank you. I had node.js v0.12 installed, indeed.